# integrating ln(1+x) using trapezoidal rule in octave

Tags: integration, octave

I was trying to integrate ln(1+x) function from 1 to 2 using trapezoidal rule in octave.My program runs,gives output also but doesn't match with the accurate answer.Though spending plenty of time on it i couldn't find the bug.
here is the function code

```
function [p] = integrationFunction ()
    n=10;
    y(n+1)=0;
    p(n+1)=0;
    a=1;b=2;h=(b-a)/n;
    for i=1:1:n+1
     y(i)=log(a+(i-1)*h);
     end
     p=y;
    endfunction
```

here is the main code.

```
p=integrationFunction();
b=2;
a=1;
n=10;
h=0.1;
trapi=0;
for i=1:1:n+1
  if(i==1 && i==(n+1))
  trapi=trapi+(h/2)*p(i);
  else
  trapi=trapi+h*p(i);
  end
  end
  trapi
```

sorry for any presentation inconvenience , new joiner of stack and in hurry also.accurate answer should be 0.90954 and mine shows  0.42054
the TRAPEZOIDAL RULE :h/2[(Y0+Yn)+2(Y1+Y2+Y3+...+Yn-1)]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't think "I'm in hurry" is a good excuse here. You are here to get help from others. They spent time for YOU and they want to see that you made some serious effort. To your question: you shouldn't create vectors in a loop like you've did in "integrationFunction". Get familiar with the language, in your case you should write `y = log(1:0.1:2)`. Second: Your check for h/2 should be the first and the last element, so you want boolean ||, not &&

Answer (score 2):

As for the 'wrong result', I suspect it's mainly that the function you're calculating is the wrong function (as well as the stuff Andy has already pointed out). You seem to be estimating the integral of `log(x)` rather than `log(1 + x)` in your code.

Having said that, there are several 'programming logic' problems above, but the main one is that you use your function in a redundant way. It would make more sense to define a function that takes the function handle to process, `n`, `a`, and `b` as arguments, and returns the result. Then your main code would simply look like this:

```
trapi = integrationFunction ( @(x) log(1 + x), 10, 1, 2 );
```

Furthermore, as others have pointed out, this kind of operation is best done in a vectorised manner in languages like octave. Obviously, if you're at the stage where you're trying to get to grips with programming and for-loops in general, this could be forgiven at this point, but it's worth keeping in mind and learning appropriate practices alongside programming basics from the beginning.

Lastly, while I sympathise a bit with the "in a hurry to learn stackoverflow formatting just to ask a question" (though I also agree with Andy's criticism on this), I would argue that proper formatting of code (and at the very least proper indentation!) is not just about presentation on online forums, but helps *you* the developer to be able to read and maintain your code, and spot mistakes easily. I suspect that had the code been more legible, the fact you were calculating the wrong function would have stood out immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the main point of a function is that it can be reused with arguments. In its current state, `integrationFunction` is hard coded which defeats the purpose of a function.

To address the integral at hand, we solve it in a [vectorised](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Basic-Vectorization.html) manner:

```
a = 1;
b = 2;
dx = (2-1) / 10000;     % set the size of each rectangle experiment with different values
f_vec = 1:dx:2;         % create a vector from 1 to 2 with intervals of dx
f_vec(1) = f_vec(1)*2;
sum(dx * log(f_vec + 1)) % apply log(x + 1) to the array, multiply by dx, sum the array.
```

See [Trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule#Numerical_implementation) for details.